# Libreoffice writer adds a line at the bottom on pressing multiple hypen and enter

Tags: libreoffice

in libreoffice writer if I type hypen (-) consecutively many times like **--------------** and then press enter then a line appears at the bottom of line [image]

How to remove this line and keep hypen as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Drawing_Lines_in_Text):

> 1. If you start a new line in a Writer text document by typing three or more hyphen characters and press the Enter key, the characters are removed and the previous paragraph gets a line as a bottom border.
>      To create a single line, type three or more hyphens (-), or underscores ( _ ), and then press Enter. To create a double line, type three or more equal signs (=), asterisks (*), tildes (~), or hash marks (#), and then press Enter.
> 2. To remove an automatically drawn border, choose Format - Paragraph - Borders and select no border.
> 3. To undo an automatic border replacement once, choose Edit - Undo.
> 4. To disable the automatic borders, choose Tools - AutoCorrect Options - Options and clear Apply border.